# ListView ViewHolder with AsyncTask : postExecute setText blocking UI

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have problems with lag in the new Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition. I think it's something with the android 4.3 version in this device, because in the 2013 version (android 2.1.3) it works far better.

The thing is:

I have implemented the viewholder pattern to show some data in a listview. I'm using SUP(sybase Unwired Server) Object API to retrieve data from ultralite database. When I have the data, some calculation has to be done, so, I show up the list, and throw an asyncTask to calculate the data.

The problem is that, a simple `setText("Whatever")` in the `postExecute`, blocks the UI. This isn't happening in the 2013 version of the Galaxy Note...

A bit of code:

**GetView:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (row == null) {
        if(Constants.DEBUG_ENABLED) Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "NEW ROW");
        row = _Inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.row_commercialconditions_search_result,
                        parent, false);             
        holder = new ViewHolder();              
        holder.vView= (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.row_valueDisc_view);
        holder.vAgrup = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.row_valueDisc_agrup);
        [...]
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        if(Constants.DEBUG_ENABLED) Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "OLD ROW");
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }           

    ConditionListItem valDisc = _Objects.get(position);

    holder.position = position;

    holder.vDist.setText(valDisc.getConditionDist());
    holder.vObjGroup.setText(valDisc.getConditionObjGroup());
    holder.vRate.setText(valDisc.getConditionRate());
    [...]
    holder.vReason.setText(valDisc.getConditionReason());
    holder.vAuthLvl.setText(valDisc.getConditionAuthLvl());

    new LoadConditionsHolderAsync(valDisc, holder,position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);          
    return row;
}
```

> **ViewHolder:**

```
static class ViewHolder {       
    TextView vProduct;
    TextView vCondType;
    TextView vVal;
    TextView vDatefrom;
    TextView vDateTo;
    TextView vDiscount;
    TextView vDiscMode;
    TextView vPeriod;
    TextView vEquidesc;
    TextView vAuthLvl;
    CheckBox vRevDamm;
    CheckBox vRevDistr;

    TextView vDist;
    TextView vObjGroup;
    TextView vReason;
    TextView vRate;
    TextView vAgrup;
    TextView vAcum;
    TextView vIncomp;

    RelativeLayout vProgress;
    int position;
    public LinearLayout vView;
}
```

> **AsyncTask:**

```
protected class LoadConditionsHolderAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    private ViewHolder mV;
    private ConditionListItem mCond;
    private int mPosition;
    private Resources mResources;
    private String mPackageName;

    String mAgrup;
    String mProduct;
    String mDatefrom;
    String mTypeCond;
    String mDateTo;
    String mDiscount;
    String mDiscMode;
    String mPeriod;
    String mState;
    String mReason;
    String mAproveLevel;
    boolean mCentral;
    String mEquidesc;
    boolean mRevDamm;
    boolean mRevDistr;
    int mBackground;



    public LoadConditionsHolderAsync (ConditionListItem cond, ViewHolder vh, int position){
        mV=vh;
        mCond = cond;
        mPosition=position;         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mV.vProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if(isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }
            mTypeCond = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_TYPE, mCond.getConditionData().getTIPO());
            mDiscMode = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_MODALITY, mCond.getConditionData().getMODALIDAD());
            mPeriod = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_PERIOD, mCond.getConditionData().getPERIODO());
            mState = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_STATE, mCond.getConditionData().getESTADO());
            mReason = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_REASON, mCond.getConditionData().getMOTIVO());
            mAproveLevel = ApplicationStatus.getHelpSearch(Constants.HV_CONDITION_APPROVAL_LEVEL, mCond.getConditionData().getNIVEL_APROB());
            return "OK";

    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result!=null && mV.position == mPosition) {
            if(Constants.DEBUG_ENABLED) Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Setting "+mV.position+"...");     
            mV.vCondType.setText(mTypeCond);
            mV.vDiscMode.setText(mDiscMode);
            mV.vPeriod.setText(mPeriod);
            mV.vVal.setText(mState);
            mV.vReason.setText(mReason);
            mV.vAuthLvl.setText(mAproveLevel);
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
```

In 2014 version, I'm seeing a lot of messages like "`AbsListView: unregisterIRlistener()` is called", I don't know if this is related...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was targetSdkVersion in the manifest. With the new device (Android 4.3), I had targetSdkVersion = 16 (Android 4.1), and I don't know exactly why, but this was causing the whole aplication to have problems with background threads.

So I updated to targetSdkVersion=18 (Android 4.3) and everything goes smooth now.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use shared variables in onBackground() and onPostExecute().

All the variables you need in onPostExecute should be returned from the doInBackground().
Then receive the values as input parameter of the  function from onPostExecute(needed parameter)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I've tried, and same behaviour happens...Even a hardcoded word in the setText blocks the UI...